# Bash script for loop runs fine but gives syntax error when run with source

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I have the following bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 4 5 6; do
  echo $i
done
```

When I run the script it works fine:

```
$ ./testbash 
4
5
6
```

When I source the same script I get the following syntax error

```
$ source testbash
bash: /home/nick/bin/testbash: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Are certain commands disallowed when sourcing a bash file? I'm using GNU bash, version 4.1.2

Here is the hexdump of the script

$ hexdump -C testbash

```
00000000  23 21 2f 62 69 6e 2f 62  61 73 68 0a 66 6f 72 20  |#!/bin/bash.for |
00000010  69 20 69 6e 20 34 20 35  20 36 3b 20 64 6f 0a 20  |i in 4 5 6; do. |
00000020  20 65 63 68 6f 20 24 69  0a 64 6f 6e 65 0a        | echo $i.done.|
0000002e
```

Comment: What sort of line endings does that file have? (What does `file testbash` say?) If you run `echo >> /home/nick/bin/testbash` and then try sourcing it again does it work?

Comment: Try `source ./testbash` to avoid it searching your path for old/outdated versions

Comment: @Etan Reisner I tried dos2linux just in case. No change. file results: testbash: Bourne-Again shell script text executable

Comment: @that `source ./testbash` resulted in the same syntax error

Comment: Execute `cat -v ./testbash` to see if there is some hidden messy character

Comment: Or start new with `printf "for i in 3 4 5; do echo \$i; done\n" > tmp.sh`, then `source tmp.sh` just to make sure it isn't a character issue.

Comment: Just to make sure I manually typed in the whole script - using two different editors. Always the same results.

Comment: What are you running it on/in? A virtual machine, Linux, something else?

Comment: Post the output of `hexdump -C testbash`. (or similar output with `od` or whatever hexdump you have)

Comment: @David tried the printf. Same result. Red hat Linux 6.5 running on the hardware

Comment: This is completely bizarre. There is no reason sourcing your script shouldn't work unless there is some embedded something in there. I've never heard of a shell setting or the like that prevents sourcing into the root terminal/shell. You are running as your normal users right? Not su'ed to some strange system user without a shell? Also, what are you running the shell in? xterm, console, gterminal??

Comment: Also, what language/`LOCALE` are you using? The only other thing I can think of would be a character interpretation issue due to a mixed language/`LOCALE` hiccup.. This may be one for the Redhat mailing list.

Comment: @David added a hexdump in the original post. Normal user. LANG=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @Dijkstra Run `env -i bash --norc` and try `source ./testfile` again in that shell. I'm guessing you have an alias called `done`.

Comment: @that Very good. There is an alias called 'done'. This fixed it.

Comment: I knew we would all laugh when it got solved -- it had to be something wonky like that. An `alias` to `done` -- **get a rope...** or **you should be shot...** `:p`

Comment: You can alias keywords??

Comment: Yes, I recall reading something about that in one of the bash/shell guides, right above the big-bold text saying **NEVER, NEVER..**. The shell will allow you to alias or otherwise assign different meanings to key words. It actually has some obscure purpose that I've never run across...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many reasons why sourcing and executing would give different results, but far fewer why you would get a new bash syntax error.

Run `env -i bash --norc` to get a clean shell so you can check whether it's related to your current shell.

If sourcing works fine in this clean shell, compare the outputs of the following commands with the shell where it fails:

1. `alias` (in case you replace or introduce keywords like `done`)
2. `shopt` (in case you modify syntax changing options like `extglob`)
3. `echo $BASH_VERSION` (in case your interactive rc files end up exec'ing a different shell)